# IF- ELSE condition - run the code in the ELSE section

Tags: javascript

I have got the following IF condition code:

```
if ((depth <= min_depth ) && (leaf_colour == "red")){

    for (i = 0; i < array_2D.length; i++) {
        var leaf_size = array_2D[i][1];

        if (leaf_size  == 10 || leaf_size  == 11){
            alert("Error message.");
            break;  // we found an error, displayed error message and now leave the loop
        }
            else{ go to the next else section }
    }
}//end of if condition 

else{

    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

Inside the 'FOR' loop, if (leaf_size  == 10 || leaf_size  == 11), we break the loop and do nothing but if this is not the case, i would like to run the code in the next ELSE section.

I do not want to copy the whole block of code and paste it inside the 'else' section of the for loop as it's quite long.

Is there a way of running the code in the second else section?

Comment: Move the code from the second `else` block into a separate function and call that function in both cases?

Comment: Maybe move the code in ELSE part to a function and call it twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ok = (depth <= min_depth ) && (leaf_colour == "red");
if (ok){

    for (i = 0; i < array_2D.length; i++) {
        var leaf_size = array_2D[i][1];

        if (leaf_size  == 10 || leaf_size  == 11){
            alert("Error message.");
            ok = false;
            break; 
        }
        else{ 
                ok = true;
                break;
            }
    }
}//end of if condition 

if(!ok) {

    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to move the code from your second `else` block into a separate function. You can then call that function wherever you need to run that code:

```
function newFunction() {
    //Shared code. This is executed whenever newFunction is called
}

if(someCondition) {
    if(someOtherCondition) {
        //Do stuff
    }
    else {
        newFunction();
    }
}
else {
    newFunction();
}
```